# Ampersand as hashmap key not working in Java?

Tags: java, properties, hashmap

I'm using a 'Properties' class in Java which inherits from `HashMap`.
I'm building a basic compiler in hashmap. I know it can be simplified using something besides a hashmap.

#### Here is the my code...

```
Properties inputSource = new Properties();
inputSource.put("ERROR", "ERROR");
inputSource.put("GET", "GET");
inputSource.put("PRINT", "PRINT");
inputSource.put("&", "&"); // this point input resource error.
```

I've tried to put "\&" instead, and it still didn't work.
Is there any way I can add a `&` as a hashmap key?

Comment: Works like a charm :) http://ideone.com/ahGiQ

Comment: Yeah, I've forgot the breakpoint. It is all my apologizes. But do you guys agree with using Haskmap as compiler [Terminal] ?

Comment: (a) What you do mean 'building a compiler'? (b) What is the point of putting strings into a map with themselves as keys? (c) what is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. The error in your case might be in some other place than you are suspecting

this is what i tried -

```
Properties inputSource = new Properties();
inputSource.put("ERROR", "ERROR");
inputSource.put("PRINT", "PRINT");
inputSource.put("&", "&"); // this point input resource error.
inputSource.put("GET", "GET");

System.out.println(inputSource.get("&"));
```

Output

```
&
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working perfectly fine for me..what is error message you are seeing? May be its your IDE showing an unnecessary warning..

(My answer should really be a comment..I got no other way..)

Answer (score 0):

just ran your code under eclipse helios, jvm 1.4.2
it works perfectly

can you pase here the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

For this particular code snippet, perhaps [HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is more appropriate. Properties seems to do far more than you need. Of course, you may have some requirements that aren't clear from your question.